# Date-Time Stamp not proper on gmail while inserting mail in c# using google apis

Tags: c#, google-api

I am trying to add mails using Google APIs.
Mail is getting inserted properly but date-time stamp is not proper.

```
 Message msg = new Message();
                String[] objidsArr = new String[1];
                objidsArr[0] = labelId;
                msg.LabelIds = objidsArr.ToList();
                msg.Raw = f_MsgRawStr;

                m_MailService.Users.Messages.Insert(msg, "me").Execute();
```

[image]

Here its showing current date-time.
But if I open it, it shows proper date like..[image]

To insert mail I use .EML file.
Please suggest solution to insert email with proper date-time in both views.

Answer (score 1):

```
f_ReqforMail = m_MailService.Users.Messages.Insert(msg, "me");
f_ReqforMail.InternalDateSource  = Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.UsersResource.MessagesResource.InsertRequest.InternalDateSourceEnum.DateHeader;
f_ReqforMail.Execute();
```

Its Working.